# Facebook Application

Tags: facebook

I'm having a problem with my Facebook application, I got an error like this.

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

What are the best solutions for this error?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the Website option active in your app settings.
Did you fill the site url there?
Thing is, if you own the site.com domain and specify it for your app, you will not be able to use a redirect url to othersite.com after login, or even domain.site.com. I think you need to specify if you are going to use subdomains.

Anyway, what sort of app are you trying to build? Is it a Canvas App? Does this error appear when you try to ask for permissions or login the user? In this case, just fill out the Site URL in your app settings page